# click derecho para editar div

Tags: angularjs

Trato de que el `div` sea editable pero al primer intento no funciona, luego si funciona, ¿cuál es el error?

> pruébenlo haciendo click en la frase

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('rightClick', function() {

  document.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
    if (e.target.hasAttribute('right-click')) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return function(scope, el, attrs) {
    el.bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
      document.getElementById('op').contentEditable = 'true';
    });
  }

});



app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>


<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="op" right-click alert="You right clciked me">Right click me</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema es que al hacer click con el botón derecho, estás haciendo que el `div` sea editable (inicialmente no lo era) al añadir `contentEditable`... pero eso es todo. Que sea editable, no quiere decir que automáticamente se entre en la edición, para eso tienes que pulsar una segunda vez (que es el comportamiento que ves).

Si lo que quieres es hacer que al hacer click el `div` se haga editable **Y** se entre en la edición, entonces además de ponerle el `contentEditable` deberías enfocar el elemento (con `focus`). Sólo tendrías que añadir una línea de código:

```
document.getElementById('op').focus();
```

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('rightClick', function() {

  document.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
    if (e.target.hasAttribute('right-click')) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return function(scope, el, attrs) {
    el.bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
      document.getElementById('op').contentEditable = 'true';
      document.getElementById('op').focus();
    });
  }

});



app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>


<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="op" right-click alert="You right clciked me">Right click me</div>
</body>
```